# IOS how metal convert fragment shader return value to MTKView.colorPixelFormat?

Tags: ios, metal

I have a question is between the fragment shader return value and MTkView.colorPixelFormat.

My fragment shader return float4, it is a 4 * 32bit vector, and MTkView.colorPixelFormat is .bgr10_xr.

how to convert float4 to .bgr10_xr? or this conversion is automatically?

Comment: It will convert `float4` automatically when writing to an attachment of any compatible format

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. Metal will do the conversion for you. Refer to section 7.7 of [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) theres an entry about 10-bit formats 7.7.4 Conversion for 10- and 11-bit Floating-Point Pixel Data Type.